# SVG background image is paving throughout the div

Tags: html, css, image, svg, background

In my mobile menu I have a `<div>` with a background SVG image which I toggle when I open or close the menu. For some reasons, this picture was paved taking all the width of this `<div>`. Any thoughts how can I change its behaviour?

Here is the screenshots:
[image]
[image]

My HTML:

```
<div class="cell-6">
    <div class="top-logo">LOGO</div>
  </div>
  <div class="cell-6" @click="showMenu = !showMenu" :class="toggleIcon">
 </div>
```

My JS:

```
toggleIcon() {
  let toggle = 'hamburger';
  if (this.showMenu === true) {
    return toggle;
  }
  toggle = 'cross';
  return toggle;
 },
},
```

My CSS:

```
.hamburger {
background: url('../img/hamburger.svg');
background-size: contain;
}
.cross {
background: url('../img/close.svg');
background-size: contain;
}
```

Comment: replace contain by the size of the svg ... and set background-repeat to no-repeat

Comment: @TemaniAfif thank you very much! It works now.